# Pipe incoming emails from google workspace to URL

Tags: php, google-workspace, email-parsing

I need to be able to parse the contents of email using PHP libraries sent to an email address hosted on Google Workspace.  When I was with HostGator they had the option to send incoming emails to a piped url where I could grab it and process ass needed.

I cannot find a similar option in the Google workspace settings.

I have not yet tried to grab the email using PHP IMAP libraries yet.  I was hoping to use the direct pipe first.

Any suggestions or direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Several different searches regarding google workspace and forwarding/redirecting to a URL did not prove any fruit.

Comment: Google Workspace does not provide a pipe option like HostGator. Why not have a look at [the options that are available in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail) and choose something there? The API option gives you the most control, the IMAP option is the most general, that means you could use your code for an Outlook mailbox as well.

Comment: Thanks, since we are also on AWS I was able to receive the email on the SES and then use SNS subscriptions and send the raw data to an HTTP address.